# Rails 6.1, Ruby 3.0.0: tests error as they cannot load rexml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-3

I've created a new Rails 6.1 application from scratch with Ruby 3.0.0.

I've run `db:create` and generated a single model with some string columns, followed by `rails db:migrate`.

I ran `rails test` but got this require rexml error:

```
/Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require': cannot load such file -- rexml/document (LoadError)
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox.rb:22:in `<main>'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/webdrivers-4.4.1/lib/webdrivers/geckodriver.rb:72:in `<main>'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/webdrivers-4.4.1/lib/webdrivers.rb:4:in `<main>'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/Rails/froop_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
  from /Users/froop/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  from <internal:/Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
  from <internal:/Users/froop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
  from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm not at all sure what's causing this. Rails is up to date. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`rexml` gem is a bundled gem since Ruby 3.0.0.
So you must add `rexml` to `Gemfile`.

On Ruby 2.6 and 2.7, `rexml` gem is default gem.
So default `rexml` is used if `Gemfile` does not include `rexml`.
On these versions of ruby, you must add `rexml` to `Gemfile` only if you want to use specific `rexml` version.

Comment: Note that bootsnap in the stack trace is misleading. If you comment out bootsnap in config/boot you'll still get an error. Adding `rexml` fixes this.

Comment: Rails test should work OOTB... is there an issue for this yet? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: is rexml is only required for tests or also for production??

Comment: I have same question as @Klaus, did you find an answer?

Answer (score 23):

To install rexml just paste: `gem 'rexml', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.4'` in Gemfile. You can find it at https://rubygems.org/gems/rexml

Answer (score 17):

#### Why is it happening now?

Ruby has been going through a process of [Gemifying Ruby](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5481) - breaking up Ruby from a standard library to Gems.

In Ruby 2.7 rexml gem is a 'default gem' which means that it could not be removed and could be required without declaring them as dependencies in Gemfiles.

In Ruby 3.0 rexml gem is a 'bundled gem':

> [Bundled gems are regular gems that ship with the default Ruby
> installation. These libraries are maintained outside the Ruby core
> team and can be uninstalled if necessary. As with other 3rd-party
> gems, you have to include them into gemspec or gemfile.](https://nts.strzibny.name/ruby-stdlib-default-bundled-gems/)

[Blog article by strzibny - What are default and bundled gems in Ruby anyway?](https://nts.strzibny.name/ruby-stdlib-default-bundled-gems/%20Bundled%20gems%20need%20to%20be%20included%20in%20the%20Gemfile.)

So, in Ruby 3.0.0 changed to a bundled gem (from being default Gem in 2.7) so if it is used it must be added to the Gemfile.